# Javascript map with ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, promise

I have JavaSctipt `Array` of `objects`, like

```
var companies = [{name:'A', userIds: [23,45], tel: 3434343434}, {name:'B', userIds: [98,568,656,54], tel: 554556445}];

function flat() {
   return companies.map(function(cmp) {
     return { 
      n: cmp.name 
      // xmlhttp remote call and callback to fetch users with these ids
      users: getUsersforThisOrg(cmp.userIds, function(usrs) { return usrs } 
     }
   });
}
var companiesWithUsers = flat();
```

Expected output of `companiesWithUsers` is

```
[
 {n:'A', users: [{username: 'user1', name: 'John Doe', ...]}, ...]
]
```

But it returns

```
[
   {n:'A', users: undefined}, ...]
]
```

it means map function returns before `getUsersforThisOrg` returns the remote result, is there any workaround to wait and append users from remote server.

Comment: you may can try rx.js and implement a solution

Comment: In short, you use Promises, and return a Promise for the object you expect. You then access your object by calling `.then()` on the Promise returned from your function.